# Open an instance of the activity which has the fragment itself

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity A which has fragment F in it. Is it possible to add another instance of same activity itself inside the fragment F?

So that this will be flow :

```
A { Fragment F -> A1 -> A2 -> B(Fragment Activity) }
```

A1 and A2 are instances of A (which is an Activiy)

Comment: fragment is hosted by a activity. So i don't understand "Is it possible to add another instance of same activity itself inside the fragment F?".

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple fragments inside an activity or you can change the fragments inside an activity or you can load the new instance of the same activity with a new fragment.

But you can't have an Activity inside a fragment.

So basically, the Flow will be :

A {Fragment F-> F1 -> F2 } -> B